# Editar registro en laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que realiza una serie de preguntas que estan organizadas en categorias, hay 2 preguntas por categoria, despues de realizada la segunda pregunta de la categoria hace un promedio de la calificacion entre ambas y la guarda en la Bd, lo hago de esta forma.

```
public function question_two(Request $request)
{
  $promedio = ($request->record + $request->record02)/2;

  $user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
  $group_id = Auth::user()->group_id;
  $student_id = $request->student_id;
  $test = Test::where('student_id', $student_id)->get()->first();
  $test_id = $test->id;

  $report = new Report();

  $report->test_id = $test_id;
  $report->user_id = $user_id;
  $report->student_id = $student_id;
  $report->enum_pts = $promedio;
  $report->calculos_m = 0;
  $report->seriacion = 0;
  $report->p_enunciados = 0;
  $report->t_operacionales = 0;
  $report->p_escala = 0;
  $report->comparacion_n = 0;

  $report->save();

  return view('test/question3', compact('student_id'));

}
```

La funcion guarda de forma correcta, el problema es que al continuar el test debo editar la tabla ya que cuando la creo, solo ingreso los resultados del primer item y los demas los relleno con cero, pero no me funciona de esta forma:

```
public function question_four(Request $request){

  $calculos_m = ($request->score + $request->record)/2;

  $report = Report::where('student_id', $request->student_id)->get();
  $report->calculos_m = $calculos_m;
}
```

Hago dd del report y pues recibe la propiedad pero no la guarda en la Bd.

```
Collection {#262 ▼
#items: array:1 [▶]
+"calculos_m": 3.5
}
```

Comment: Tal vez falta `$report->save();` ?

Comment: Lo intente pero me salia este error: `BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method save does not exist.`

Comment: En teoría eso es porque no estás haciendo `use Report;`. Viendo con calma el método question_two(), deberías usar inyección de dependencias en vez de hacer `$report = new Report();`, aunque eso no tiene que ver con el problema actual.

Comment: Perdón copie el msj de error que no era, si agrego el use App\Report; arriba, pero me dice que el metodo save() no existe o algo así.

Comment: entonces prueba usando `first()` en vez de `get()`, asumiendo que haya solo un registro por estudiante, y luego sí usas `save()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con first() ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando `get()` que obtiene un arreglo de resultados, deberías usar `first()` para obtener un solo registro y utilizar el método `save()` para guardar el registro deseado.

Pequeña nota: es preferible siempre usar inyección de dependencias en vez de instanciar una clase directamente en el controlador.